# Supported URLs for video embedding

Tags: support, faq, formatting

How does video embedding work? What URLs are recognized? Is it possible to link to a particular time in a video? Is video embedding also enabled on this Meta site?

(Posting this as a sort of sandbox question, since there doesn't seem to be one on any other SE that has embedding enabled. See [this Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273197/enable-video-embeds-that-start-at-a-specific-time) for more context.)

Answer (score 8):

> How does video embedding work?

A link to a YouTube video, where the link text is the same as the href (typically a [bare URL](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#bare-urls), but it can also be done using Markdown syntax) will be converted to an [embedded video](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en).

> Is video embedding also enabled on this Meta site?

Yes. See the end of this answer for an example.

> What URLs are recognized?

The following URL formats appear to be recognized:

```
Youtube's main domain:
   http://youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M
   https://youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M    
Youtube's www subdomain:
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M
Youtube Mobile "m" subdomain:
   http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M
   https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M
Youtube's Url Shortener:
   http://youtu.be/rEWaqUVac3M
   https://youtu.be/rEWaqUVac3M
```

There is no other standard or common url that Youtube uses at this time.

> Is it possible to link to a particular time in a video?

Yes. You can directly use the URL that YouTube provides when using the "Copy video URL at current time" functionality from the video's right-click menu, which is the short video URL with `?t=XX` appended (where XX is the offset in seconds). You can also use the `?start=XX` parameter, or the `?t=XmYYs` (minutes and seconds) form. When adding a time offset to a video that already has a query string (the section starting from the question mark), use an ampersand `&` instead of a question mark.

For example, the following URLs are all equivalent:

```
https://youtu.be/rEWaqUVac3M?t=110
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M&start=110
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M&t=1m50s
```

and will all result in the following embedded video cued to the appropriate time:

In direct links, YouTube normally supports specifying the start time in a fragment identifier as well (`#t=XmYYs`), but SE doesn't recognize that form for video embeds.