# Please Improve Youtube URL Parsing

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, formatting

**Update:** These seems to be asked on Meta.Se as [Please Improve supported URLs list for Embedded YouTube videos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269769/277339#277339). It has very little support. I posted the below as an answer to try to improve views for the question. Please upvote it so that it gets some traction.

---

**Sometimes youtube urls arnt parsed if it doesn't fit a specific format.
Can we request that it be expanded?**

***Please add***
Mobile links with the "m." subdomain

- https ex:`https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=71fWtJXEI0Q`
- http
  ex:`http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=71fWtJXEI0Q`

No Subdomain

- https ex: `https://youtube.com/watch?v=71fWtJXEI0Q`
- http ex: `http://youtube.com/watch?v=71fWtJXEI0Q`

Shortened by youtube's shortener

- https ex: `https://youtu.be/rEWaqUVac3M`

Per a related question, [Supported URLs for video embedding](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2105/49) the current supported ones are:

> ```
> http://youtu.be/rEWaqUVac3M
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M
> ```

While some unsupported ones are:

> ```
> https://youtu.be/rEWaqUVac3M
> http://youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M
> https://youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M
> ```

Comment: The shortened version works, though, just not with `https`.

Comment: Related: [Supported URLs for video embedding](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2105/49)

Comment: So yeah basically request to support the ones not supported yet.

Comment: @cde you'd probably need to go raise this on meta.SE, then, since I assume it's a software change.

Comment: @KutuluMike That question is about chat oneboxing. But, yes. This doesn't really affect only M&TV, so it's better on  Meta.SE

Comment: The Meta post I was looking for is [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269769/embed-youtube-videos-from-variant-urls). Which, I think, is the question you're asking, though it's not as broad as this. Perhaps a request-supporting answer with the newer URLs that aren't currently supported?

Comment: There are also issues with embedding Youtube videos with timestamps, IIRC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All sounds good; fixed in code - available after the next deploy (when the "rev" at the bottom of the screen is higher than "2016.3.23.3373")

Comment: Tested and confirmed with each of the example ones above. All are parsed properly. Thank you for the quick fix.